# Jmeter URISyntaxException when trying to put id from jdbc request

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

In Jmeter I' m trying to set an id as variable in my http get request URL url/api/test/${id}

I use an Preprocessor JDBC request in order to obtain the id

After executing the request I got this error
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path url/api/test/${id}/[{id=A9A89EE6-A446-4164-87BE-0157FD7170FA}].

The id is placed in the URL but there is other symbols that  shouldn't appear there.

Thank you in advance for all advice/help etc.

I tried to pass id in jdbc request in different manners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `id` from the "Result Variable Name"
2. Use `${id_1}` where you need to use the variable from the database

More information:

- [JDBC Request Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)
- [How to Debug JMeter Test Scripts](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)